# Gray prototype type look when data is not loaded

Tags: website-design, gui-design, user-engagement

I have noticed recently that many sites use a gray prototype type look when loading data on page.

- Exhibit 1- **Google drive**
  [image: Exhibit 1- Google drive]
- Exhibit 2- **Facebook**
  [image: facebook]
- Exhibit 3- **Medium**
  [image: medium]

Can some one explain what library is used for this effect and how does it work in principle?
Is there a study/A-B test/research which suggests that this approach help in any way in keeping user engaged while content is loaded?

Comment: This answer could help https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/115119/66972. Unfortunately your question about what library is used relate on implementation and will be probably off-topic here.

Comment: @Brice this is exactly what I was looking for. At least now I know that Apple human interface guidelines originated them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is a link to research specifically (certainly none that I have seen). I think this is something that companies have come across in research.

Its used to give the user an indication as to where things are right away, make wait times feel shorter and is a better alternative to the standard loading state (loading wheel/bar/indicator). As apposed to being used to keep users interested, its a little more than that.

Here is some further reading on it that I have come across while looking to use this for our products:

- [Placeholder while loading](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/109178/placeholder-while-loading)
- [Place holder UI and its benefits](https://medium.com/anatomy-of-web-interface/placeholder-loading-ui-bbaf2222f95f)
- [How it works](https://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html)
- [Making Wait times feel shorter](http://usabilitypost.com/2009/01/23/making-wait-times-feel-shorter/)
- [Why the loading wheel doesn't work](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/stop-using-loading-spinner-theres-something-better/)

Answer (score 1):

Some additional libraries and resources people might find helpful:

- [BLOKK Font](http://www.blokkfont.com/)
- [Loader View For Android](https://github.com/elye/loaderviewlibrary)
- [Building Skeleton Screens with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/building-skeleton-screens-css-custom-properties/)
- [JQuery Skeleton Loader](https://github.com/enbifa/jquery.skeleton.loader)
- [Skeleton View Loader Library](https://github.com/ethanhua/Skeleton)